# How to prevent commonsChunkPlugin from injecting the chunks into html

Tags: webpack, commonschunkplugin

I am using preload-webpack-plugin along with the commonschunkplugin for webpack. My webpack version is 3.

Now the issue is that using the preloadplugin, I am already prefetching the async routes in my vue application. But since commonschunkplugin is also used, after page load, it also injects tags like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="/static/js/3.3c5729583b9ce21e8fd8.js"></script>
```

So, as a result, the page becomes like this -

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/static/js/0.806cdda5777e81bb1a8b.js">
<link rel="prefetch" href="/static/js/1.95cf2f4474949209d50b.js">
<link rel="prefetch" href="/static/js/2.5231ce0aada93adb0dd7.js">
<link rel="prefetch" href="/static/js/3.6eef2cb918c01f721e28.js">
<link rel="prefetch" href="/static/js/4.228c75e21459a43cb71c.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="/static/js/0.806cdda5777e81bb1a8b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="/static/js/4.228c75e21459a43cb71c.js"></script>
```

I don't want those last 2 script tags to be inserted, because I am already prefetching them.

This is my relavant webpack config -

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // preloading assets
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      rel: 'prefetch'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks (module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),
```

I had this working in a previous project. But somehow I can't figure out why in this project, these async tags keep getting injected. I have matched the same webpack version, tried all sorts of config variations but nothing has worked.

Any sort of help on this would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that injects those scripts to the HTML is the HTMLWebpackPlugin, you have 2 options:

1. Use [`excludeChunks`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks) option to specify which chunks to ignore.
2. Use [`chunks`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks) option to specify what chunks to include.

Comment: Ah you are right. That works. But now if I change the HTMLWebpackPlugin not to inject those chunks, my app doesn't work :( I swear this worked earlier in my last project. Can't seem to figure out what is different now.

Comment: Yes. Through async route loading in vuejs.